# How to achieve PVC pipe slope

Tags: plumbing

This seems like a really silly question, but I haven't been able to find the answer (maybe because it's so obvious).  I commonly see that PVC piping should be run at a minimum slope of 1/4" per foot.  That's great and all, but the only connectors I know of come in 45 and 90 degrees.

If I have a pipe that is coming down vertically, how do I make the 90'ish degree turn to assure I maintain this minimum slope?  I saw this question [How to get down slope on drain lines?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/how-to-get-down-slope-on-drain-lines) but it only had one un-accepted answer.  It seems a little odd that the answer would just be "bend it till it fits".  Why don't they make 110 degree fittings if this is a standard thing?  What if the end of your pipe is free open? How would you achive that angle?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your linked question. The reason they don't make "other" angles is that they'd be 91.2° instead of 90°. PVC flexes enough that it's not an issue.

Comment: I'm guessing that they don't make them at different angles because these are standard, most usual ones. Like Doresoom said PVC pipes when they are just few meters long (1 meter=3 feet) are flexible enough to provide a slope. You can make the slope by laying some sand at the bottom of the trench and them adjusting it under certain angles. Also you can put small wooden sticks and nail them in to the ground every few inches replicating the slope you want to achieve. Then you will have height for sand bed.  (go read next comment)

Comment: ...At the end before you bury the trench there is a small trick which I use to check the slope: Take a marble and drop it on the entrance point of the sewerage (don't drop it in toilet because it has "S" curve) and just wait for it at the end of the pipe....if it comes out great, if not..something is wrong.